# Separation of the logic of tutorial from the main app logic

Tags: c#, solid-principles, object-oriented-analysis

Here we are developing an email client software which has a specific UI that we need to teach that to the user.

There are some classes which handle the logic of the application. for example there is function like this in the one of main classes of project:

```
public void ComposeMessage(string username,string message)
{
    MessageComposer.ComposeMessage(username, message);
}
```

so, in the above function we send a message to a user.

but in the another side of the application; there is a tutorial phase . so when user goes into tutorial side of the application , he can interact with application's buttons which we tell him , but we don't want to send real messages. so we have changed the function above like this:

```
public void ComposeMessage(string username,string message)
{
    if(!Global.IsTutorial)
        MessageComposer.ComposeMessage(username, message);
}
```

So there are many functions which we are adding ***`if(!Global.IsTutorial)`*** in their body. How can we avoid this situation? We don't want to change the body of the functions in the tutorial section and we don't want to add more codes and classes into our project. We want to keep changes low as much as possible.

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot of ways to achieve what you want but all of them imply that, to start with, you don't use `ComposeMessage` directly but create interface for it and refactor callers to inject it as a dependency:

```
public interface IMessageComposer
{
    void ComposeMessage(string username, string message);
}

public class MyApp
{
    IMessageComposer messageComposer;

    public MyApp(IMessageComposer messageComposer)
    {
        this.messageComposer = messageComposer;
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        messageComposer.ComposeMessage(username, message);
    }
}
```

When you don't rely on concrete implementation and inject dependencies you may change implementation of `IMessageComposer` to whatever you like without actually touching original `MessageComposer`'s or `MyApp`'s code.

For example you can create `TutorialMessageComposer` like this

```
public class TutorialMessageComposer : IMessageComposer
{
    public void ComposeMessage(string username, string password)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Tutorial mode!");
    }
}
```

And `RoutingMessageComposer` decorator which will check current mode and call right composer

```
public class RoutingMessageComposer : IMessageComposer
{
    IMessageComposer composer;
    IMessageComposer tutorialComposer;

    public RoutingMessageComposer(IMessageComposer composer, IMessageComposer tutorialComposer)
    {
        this.composer = composer;
        this.tutorialComposer = tutorialComposer;
    }

    public void ComposeMessage(string username, string message)
    {
        if (Global.IsTutorial)
            tutorialComposer.ComposeMessage(username, message);
        else
            composer.ComposeMessage(username, message);    
    }
}
```

After all preparations completed, you just need to stick `RoutingMessageComposer` into `MyApp`

```
var app = new MyApp(new RoutingMessageComposer(new MessageComposer(), new TutorialMessageComposer()));
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply, but suppose that in the tutorial mode , there is real sending , or there is no send operation

Comment: So how is proposed solution won't work in this case? You may put whatever logic you like inside `TutorialMessageComposer`.

Comment: Did you mean that if  want to do nothing in the tutorial mode, I should left TutorialMessageComposer empty?

Comment: @s.ahmadparkhid yes, that's exactly what he means.  when you use an interface you can have totally different logic in each different implementation.

Comment: @s.ahmadparkhid Yes. You can leave it empty or just print some message to log or you can send different message to different set of receivers.